# Extract item from a list with logical test (min, max)

Tags: r

I have a list of lists. I want to be able to query the sub-lists to determine which has the maximum value for an element within and return that list.

e.g. in the following list:

```
myList <- list(
        list(ID = 1, Sales = 1000, Product = "Car"),
        list(ID = 2, Sales = 2000, Product = "Boat"),
        list(ID = 3, Sales = 1500, Product = "Bike")
              )
```

I would make a query along the lines of:

```
myList[["where the value for myList$Sales is the maximum across all elements of the same type (i.e. sales) in the list"]])
```

And would be returned `list(ID = 2, Sales = 2000, Product = "Boat")`

Is this type of querying within lists feasible / straightforward?  Is there a package that can handle this situation better than Base R?

Comment: library(data.table) dt <- rbindlist(myList)
dt[which.max(Sales),]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the `Sales` and use `which.max` to get the index of the element with maximum sales, i.e.

```
myList[which.max(sapply(seq_along(myList), function(i) myList[[i]]$Sales))]

#myList[which.min(sapply(seq_along(myList), function(i) myList[[i]]$Sales))] for the MIN


#$ID
#[1] 2

#$Sales
#[1] 2000

#$Product
#[1] "Boat"
```

---

Or another way as per @zx8754 suggested:

```
myList[ which.max(sapply(myList, "[", "Sales")) ]
```

Comment: A bit simpler would be: `myList[ which.max(sapply(myList, "[", "Sales")) ]`

Comment: Thanks guys.  I've gone with @zx8754 as it is, as you suggest, a bit simpler / more concise.

Comment: Incidentally, how does this sort of function perform on a large list?  Obviously the example I provided is quite short so runs almost instantly.  Are there any observed issues with this type of operation on a larger list and should an alternative data construct (e.g. data.table) be considered beyond a certain point?